# jquery else and if statements help on scroller position

Tags: jquery

I wanted to add an active class depending on the scroll position thankful I found this that had already been posted:

[jQuery : add css class to menu item based on browser scroller position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703086/jquery-add-css-class-to-menu-item-based-on-browser-scroller-position)

I have an extra navigation item to this tutorial, and do not know how to arrange the if, else if and else statements.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
// find the li with class 'active' and remove it
$("#navigation li.active").removeClass("active");
// get the amount the window has scrolled
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
// add the 'active' class to the correct li based on the scroll amount
if (scroll <= 500) {
    $("#nav-welcome").addClass("active");
}
else if (scroll <= 1000) {
    $("#nav-about").addClass("active-purple");
}
else if (scroll <= 1500) {
    $("#nav-portfolio").addClass("active");
}
else {
    $("#nav-contact").addClass("active-purple");
}
});
```

I'm getting two active classes where I've used the two else ifs.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (scroll >= 1500)  {
    $("#nav-portfolio").addClass("active");
} else if (scroll >= 1000) {
    $("#nav-about").addClass("active-purple");
} else if (scroll >= 500) {
    $("#nav-welcome").addClass("active");
} else {
    $("#nav-contact").addClass("active-purple");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's partly working although it's activating the last else statement - nav-contact inbetween scrolling between nav-welcome and nav-about and when scrolling back up it activates nav-contact instead od nav-welcome.

Comment: The way you had it set up was sort of confusing. When you're at the top of the page, what do you want it to be on?