# Adding a class on scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll

I am trying to simply add the class `active` on window scroll and remove it when not scrolled.

I tried to follow these directions located here:
[jQuery : add css class to menu item based on browser scroller position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703086/jquery-add-css-class-to-menu-item-based-on-browser-scroller-position)

However, I still must be doing something wrong. Nothing is happening to the id `myCart` when scrolling.

I have the following html:

```
<div id="myCart" class="active">
<div class="add-to-cart">
<div class="clearfix qty_ticker">
<label for="qty">Qty:</label>
<span class="marker_qty_left"> </span>
<input id="qty" class="input-text qty" type="text" title="Qty" value="1" maxlength="12" name="qty">
<span class="marker_qty_right"> </span>
</div>
<button class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)" title="Add to Cart" type="button">
<span>
<span>Add to Cart</span>
</span>
</button>
</div>
</div>
```

And the following javascript or jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    // find the id with class 'active' and remove it
    $("#myCart").removeClass("active");
    // get the amount the window has scrolled
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    // add the 'active' class to the correct id based on the scroll amount
    if (scroll <= 500) {
        $("#myCart").addClass("active");
    }
});
</script>
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing ")" at the end of your script which is causing the javascript not to compile.

Code should be

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    // find the id with class 'active' and remove it
    $("#myCart").removeClass("active");
    // get the amount the window has scrolled
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    // add the 'active' class to the correct id based on the scroll amount
    if (scroll <= 500) {
        $("#myCart").addClass("active");
    }
});
</script>
```

When you are using both jquery and prototype, the jquery's $ global variable conflicts with prototypes $ global variable.  One way to fix that is to use jquery's jQuery variable as such

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
var $$ = jQuery;
$$(window).scroll(function() {    
    // find the id with class 'active' and remove it
    $$("#myCart").removeClass("active");
    // get the amount the window has scrolled
    var scroll = $$(window).scrollTop();
    // add the 'active' class to the correct id based on the scroll amount
    if (scroll <= 500) {
        $$("#myCart").addClass("active");
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! However, its still not doing anything for some reason. My website is http://50.87.6.244/~storeupp/index.php/basketball/full-sample-product.html This element is the second add to cart button. Can you have a look and see why its not doing anything. The class active just stays there.

Comment: Seems you are missing jquery on your page or atleast I can't find it.  Try adding <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: @tech0925 Are you sure there is a class named 'active' ?

Comment: I added that right above the code and it makes it work. However, in my header, for some reason there is already 1.6.2 and 1.7.1 versions included. Also when I add yours above the code it makes half the other jquery scripts not work properly. What do you suggest? @Himal yes there is a class called active.

Comment: Use the newest version of jQuery only, no point in having other version of jQuery on the same page.

Comment: Thanks @RyanFishman for helping! I really do appreciate it! I removed all those other instances of jquery and updated it to the latest one that you provided. Everything on the page still works fine except for the above code. I placed it in the header but still no luck. Any ideas??

Comment: When I type in $('#myCart') I see the value null which means jquery is not null.  I also see you are using a library prototype.js which conflicts with jquery's $.  If you replace $ with jQuery in your code it should work.

Comment: Can you update your code above to reflect that so I can see what you mean? Again, thanks so much!

Comment: You are the man @RyanFishman !! Thank you so much for taking the time to help me with that. I still got so much to learn about jquery :)